# Having trouble with alternate shading and hidden cells in SQL Server Reporting Services

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, formatting, ssrs-2012, shading

The main method I have for altering the formatting of the final reports is in SQL Server Report Builder.

I have a table within this system which currently is as shown below with some information blacked out.

[image: Current Shading]

As shown currently the second line (as shown by 004A) of groupings (referred to as a subsample) comes up with blank areas in the second, third, and fifth columns where the cells have been hidden.

This shading has been done with the following code:

```
=Iif(Left(Fields!LabSampleNo.Value,3) MOD 2 = 0, "WhiteSmoke", "Transparent")
```

Is there a way to fix this issue without having to go to coding outside the report builder or by making the fields no longer hidden?

Any help would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the textboxes are hidden you will not be able to see the backcolor. It is the entire textbox you are hiding, not just it's content.

So the answer to your question is no, you will have to make the textboxes visible again **however** you can just wrap your value expression inside the same logic as you used to hide the columns.

So, let's say you are hiding the columns based on the first column have non numeric characters and the column you wanted to hide was called `myDataColumn` then you could do something like...

```
=IIF(ISNUMERIC(Fields!myFirstColumn.Value), Fields!myDataColumn.Value, "")
```

Your row's `background color` expression would remain the same.